# Infinite sum of little Oh terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I prove that if  $|a_{nk}| = o(b_{nk})$ as $n \to \infty$ for each $k$, then  $\sum_{k=1}^n |a_{nk}| = o( \sum_{k=1}^n b_{nk} )$?

EDIT: David C. Ullrich showed this isn't true in general.

However, if we have uniform convergence of $|a_{nk}|/b_{nk}$ to zero, then we can conclude that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $N$ high enough such that for $n > N$, $|a_{nk}| < \epsilon \times b_{nk}$ for every $k$.

Summing on each side,

$\sum_{k=1}^n|a_{nk}| < \epsilon\sum_{k=1}^n b_{nk} $

which shows that $\sum_{k=1}^n|a_{nk}| = o(\sum_{k=1}^n b_{nk})$

Comment: Why do you think this is true?

Comment: This needn't be true as stated. If the number of terms being summed was fixed, then you could just use the definition of little oh to get some $N_k$'s so that $|a_{nk}|/b_{nk}$ is small for all $n \geq N_k$ and then take the maximum over $k$. But with the number of terms not fixed you have a problem, in that the convergence rate of $|a_{nk}|/b_{nk}$ to zero could become progressively slower as $k \to \infty$, which can spoil your desired statement.

Comment: You are both right. I believe uniform convergence is necessary for the statement to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample:

Let $b_{nk}=2^{-k}$. Let $$a_{nk}=\begin{cases}1,&(n\le k^2),
\\0,&(n>k^2).\end{cases}$$

Then $\sum_{k=1}^na_{nk}$ is roughly $n-\sqrt n$, wich tends to infinity, while $\sum_{k=1}^nb_{nk}$ is bounded.

Comment: Just a little followup from my previous comment: in this example if $\varepsilon<1$ then $N_k=k^2+1$ which isn't bounded, so one cannot simply take its supremum over $k$.